# Performance degradation due to loading a shared library with thread local storage

Tags: multithreading, performance, openmp, thread-local-storage

I write a python wrapper around a large Fortran program with pybind11 as a python module. The Fortran program is a large simulation tool, that uses OpenMP for multithreading. My initial work was to reproduce the Fortran executable from a python function. That yielded (as expected) exactly the same results and the same performance. But when I started to add more functions, I observed a large performance degradation (about 50% to 100% longer runtimes).

## Tracking the cause in pybind11

I could track it down to a call of the pybind11 macro `PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE`, which loads in its internals the numpy library `numpy.core._multiarray_umath`. I could reproduce the performance degradation with the following code:

```
import ctypes
import time

# This is the fortran code, compiled to a shared library and a subroutine modulemain, that resembles the main program.
fcode = ctypes.CDLL("./libfcode.so")

# Only loading the library results in a worse performance of the Fortran code.
import numpy.core._multiarray_umath

t = time.time()
fcode.modulemain()
print("runtime: ", time.time()-t)
```

## Tracking the cause in numpy

After finding, that the reason of my bad performance lies just in including the `numpy.core._multiarray_umath` library, I further digged into it. Ultimately I could track it down to two lines in that library, where two variables with thread local storage a defined.

```
// from numpy 1.21.5, numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c:4011
static NPY_TLS int sigint_buf_init = 0;
static NPY_TLS NPY_SIGJMP_BUF _NPY_SIGINT_BUF;
```

where `NPY_TLS`is defined as

```
#define NPY_TLS __thread
```

So the inclusion of a shared object with `__thread` TLS is the root cause for my performance degradation. This leads me to my two questions:

1. Why?
2. Is there any way to prevent it? Not using `PYBIND11_NUMPY_DTYPE` is no option, as the loading of the numpy library after my module will trigger the bug as well!

## Minimal working example

My error is about a large and heavy Fortran code, that I wanted to export to python via pybind11. But in the end it resulted in a problem of using OpenMP thread local storage and then loading a library that exports a variable with `__thread` thread local storage in the python interpreter. I could create a minimal working example, that reproduced the behavior.

**The worker program work.f90**

```
module data
  integer, parameter :: N = 10000
  real :: X(1:N)
  !$omp threadprivate(X)
end module

subroutine work() bind(C, name="worker")
  use data, only: X,N

  !$omp parallel
  X(1) = 0.131
  do i=2,N
    do j=1,i-1
      X(i) = X(i) + 0.431*sin(X(i-1))
    end do
  end do
  !$omp end parallel
```

**The bad library tl.c**

```
__thread int badVariable = 3;
```

**a python script that shows the effect run.py**

```
import ctypes
import time

work = ctypes.CDLL("./libwork.so")

# first worker run without loaded libtl.so. Good performance!
t = time.time()
work.worker()
print("TIME: ", time.time()-t)

# load the bad library
bad = ctypes.CDLL("./libtl.so")

# second worker with degraded performance
t = time.time()
work.worker()
print("TIME: ", time.time()-t)
```

**The Makefile**

```
FLAGS = -fPIC  -shared

all: libwork.so libtl.so

libwork.so: work.f90
        gfortran-11 $(FLAGS) work.f90 -fopenmp -o $@

libtl.so: tl.c
        gcc-11 $(FLAGS) tl.c -o $@
```

The worker is so simple, that enabling optimization will hide the effect. I guess is could be a call to access the thread local storage area, that could be easily optimized out here. But in a real program, the effect is there with optimization.

## Setup

I have the problem on a ubuntu 22.04 LTS computer with a x86 CPU (Xeon 8280M). gcc is Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 (I tried others down to  7.5.0 with the same effect). Python is version 3.10.6.
The problem is not Fortran specific, I can easily write a worker in plain C with the same effect. And I also tried this on a Raspberry Pi with the same effect! (ARM, GCC 8.3.0, Python 2.7.16)

Comment: I found some resources on this, including this [blog post on TLS performance](http://david-grs.github.io/tls_performance_overhead_cost_linux/) which also links to [Ulrich Drepper's description of the implementation](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf) Looks to me like most of the issue should be with thread construction. Does the overhead go away when you repeatedly use parallel sections? Also, do you use nested parallelization? Because that is known to create new threads instead of reusing them

Comment: As far as I see, the Fortran code does not use nested parallelization. At the moment, my best guess is, that the code is quite sensitive to the overhead introduced by TLS. I did some more tests and found, that I get a even larger performance penalty when I compare an executable done via "normal" linking with one that uses most of the code through a shared library. I will read the reference that you have provided. Maybe this will help me to understand the problem.